# Android studio 3.1.2 Design of app different than what is running on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I just started learning app development and i made an app with 2 buttons at the center of the screen, 1 below the other using the design tab of the constraintlayout's .xml file. But when i run it on my device only the second button is shown, that too it as at the top left corner. Can someone please help me(a beginner). Also please tell me how to change it to relative layout!

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I think you're going to need to add something more to go on.  Are you able to include your layout here?

Comment: show what you already did

Answer (score 0):

The default layout you get when creating a new layout file is called `ConstraintLayout`. If you want to position any of your views (`Buttons`, `TextViews` etc.) inside of it you'll have to constrain them to other views or the window, otherwise they will jump to top left inside of your application.

I assume that you have just added 2 `Buttons` with the graphical designer and placed them on the center of the layout without constraining them to anything, so inside of the xml file they should look something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="132dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="156dp" />
```

Android Studio should display a warning when you hover over the `<Button` about lack of constraints. The last 2 lines of the xml are for positioning your view inside the designer, but they don't reflect the positioning inside of your application. If you want to position the views you have to constrain them to other views like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
```

The button is now constrained to it's parent on all 4 sides which means it will be centered horizontally and vertically inside of it's parent. A layout with 2 centered buttons could look like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/topButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Top button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomButton"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bottom button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
```

As you can see the `Buttons` are constrained to each other. If you want to use `RelativeLayout` you can just change the root layout of your xml file from `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to `RelativeLayout`.

Personally I'd recommend learning how to use `ConstraintLayout` though because it's the most powerful layout and the one that Google is trying to make everyone use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I'm a beginner, could you please explain those added constraints like that top_to_topof, etc. like what they do or how is the position of the button affected by those constraints.